# click events and css attributes not attaching to divs, possibly because divs are "mostly padding"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to attach click events to a couple of divs. One of which has no height or width, just borders. Maybe it's just the browser, but the clicks are being triggered very unreliably. Even the css parameters `.class:hover{}` isn't really working.

```
$("body").on("click", "._tlh_dropdown, ._tlh_dropdown *", function (event) {
```

isn't working when the a div contained by `._tlh_dropdown` is clicked. And the div `._tlh_dropdown_close_button` is not removing it's parent div when clicked, nor turning a darker shade of gray when it is hovered over. What am I doing wrong here? I assume it has to do with the click event not being applied to the areas of the divs that are "just padding". Is this the case? How can I overcome this?

http://jsfiddle.net/UrNUM/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the underline element that is a div element overlaps the elements in question . As you know `div` is a block level element.

One work around is to to set the 2 divs to `inline-block`

```
._tlh_dropdown_input_container, ._tlh_dropdown{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle for hover](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UrNUM/8/)**

If you want the `div` to be block level as it is then you can also play around with the z-index

```
._tlh_dropdown_close_button{
     z-index: 1;   
}
```

This will make sure the close div is always on top of the underlying container

**UPDATE**

2 events fire for every click event on the page..

So the content is not shown when u click on the image because of this condition

```
if ($targ.hasClass('_tlh_dropdown') 
      || $targ.closest('._tlh_dropdown_content').length)

return;
```

This happens because the `e.target` when you click on the arrow image will be the arrow and not the `tlh_dropdown` .. So it fails on this condition and moves to the next statement where the content is removed.

Change it

```
if ($targ.hasClass('_tlh_dropdown') 
       || $targ.closest('._tlh_dropdown').length  
       || $targ.closest('._tlh_dropdown_content').length) 
 return;
```

It should work..

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UrNUM/9/)**

Also I feel the same can be accomplished with a lot less code. You can always have the `HTML` already built and then hide or show based on the condition.

Comment: Perfect. What is the "underline element that is a div" though? Thank you so much!

Comment: Check `._tlh_dropdown_input_container` element . Open dev tools and inspect the element . You can see the outline of the element that overlaps the close button

Comment: yes, i was playing around with z-index. that seems to work as well for the close button. But the div triangle still isn't registering the click. Any ideas on getting it to register? Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for this really great answer. I usually do this kind of thing with a hide/show, but I've just been experimenting with the dynamic creation today to see if I find it in any way preferable. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the close button, if you hover "_tlh_dropdown_input_container" in the inspector, you can see that it overlaps the bottom part of the X button. That's why the hover/click event on the X is not caught below the middle of it.

Regarding the down arrow, just wrap it with another DIV on which you'll add the events. You can achieve minimal HTML by using a single DIV and adding the arrow to it using CSS :before or :after.